# WSDL Visible in browser but accesible from SoapUI

Tags: wsdl, soapui

I have created a web service, i can see the wsdl in the browser but when i try to access it from soapUI i get the following error.

HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 21 Jul 2015 14:00:57 GMT

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you looking for a certain user agent?

Comment: It could be a proxy issue. You might need add proxy configuration in soap ui. or it could be an issue with the imports used in the wsdl. Please try accessing the wsld in browser and if you find any import in it , try to access those import urls in your  browser.

Comment: It got a 404 so I think it found the server, but not the WSDL.  Are you certain the WSDL URL is the same?